# ASP.Net and ASPNETBD (separate database)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

ASP.Net has stock classes for Roles and Memberships. We can use `aspnet_regsql.exe` to create the login database. The login database created by `aspnet_regsql.exe` is separate from the application database so that multiple applications can use the same login database.

My question is, what are the security implications to using a separate database? Is it better to use a single database (with login and app data) to reduce surface error (ie, single connection to one database).

Comment: Some would argue that having separate databases is actually better as you can encrypt the userId/password one and that when people are mulling around in the application database to work on problems/issues/ they can't learn peoples usernames/passwords.  IT also makes it harder to associate data in the application database to a specific user; thus obfuscating data should a system be hacked.

Comment: Are two separate connection strings/UIDs required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are telling ASP.NET Membership to store your passwords as a hash, then there's no risk to the data being compromised. Putting the data in a separate database won't necessarily protect it - if the database is on the same server then a join can still be accomplished using a fully-qualified object name [database].[schema].[table] to join tables from different databases.